# i18next missing key whereas the key exists?

Tags: localization, internationalization, i18next

I often get the following error:

`i18next::translator: missingKey fr common my key.`

whereas the key is in the translation file (which is correctly loaded and taken into account). Why?

**Edit:** 
This happens when I have a `.` (dot character) in a key in the translation file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The translation file must be a valid JSON file and cannot contain keys with the `.` (dot) character. i18next will complain of a missing key if the key contains a dot.

Comment: if having keys with `.` just set the keySeparator to false on init.

Answer (score 3):

If i could guess i'm rather sure you're accessing the `t` function to early -> before the translations where loaded from the backend.

```
i18next.init({
  lng: 'en',
  debug: true
}, function(err, t) {
  // initialized and ready to go!
  i18next.t('key'); // -> ok
});

i18next.t('key'); // -> not ok as not yet loaded translations
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
  // allow keys to be phrases having `:`, `.`
keySeparator: false, 
nsSeparator: false,
```

Add that to your i18n.js inside `i18n.use(LanguageDetector).init({})`

Documentation https://www.i18next.com/principles/fallback#key-fallback